# How would I write an HLSL bevel shader for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, shader, hlsl, bitmapeffect

I know that Silverlight doesn't directly support the WPF bitmap effects, but I also know that Silverlight 3 supports HLSL shaders. Would it be relatively simple to write a bevel effect, ilke the one in WPF, and if so, can somebody recommend a good resource to learn how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d19828e7-560e-4733-97b4-63326be8390c/

Answer (score 0):

Vote below for adding muilti-pass shaders which would make this possible.

http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/40583-wpf-feature-suggestions/suggestions/480961-add-gloweffect-and-multipass-shaders-